# Three.js mesh from blender json not showing

Tags: json, three.js, blender

I am using three.js and I converted a blend to json that I want to use in three.js. When I display it without using the material in the json (I just used a BasicMaterial()) it works fine. When I try to use the material in the json it doesn't seem to render it.

This is the code that I am using to display the mesh:

```
var tower;
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load( 'js/blends/towerlevel1-5.json', function ( geometry, material)   
{
        tower = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        scene.add( tower);
});
```

This is the json materials:

```
"materials":[{
        "visible":true,
        "shading":"phong",
        "wireframe":false,
        "DbgIndex":0,
        "mapBumpRepeat":[1,1],
        "opacity":1,
        "mapDiffuse":"Wood.jpg",
        "mapBumpScale":[0.2,0.2],
        "mapBumpWrap":["RepeatWrapping","RepeatWrapping"],
        "colorEmissive":[0,0,0],
        "DbgName":"Wood2",
        "mapDiffuseAnisotropy":1,
        "mapDiffuseWrap":["RepeatWrapping","RepeatWrapping"],
        "DbgColor":15658734,
        "depthTest":true,
        "depthWrite":true,
        "specularCoef":50,
        "blending":"NormalBlending",
        "colorSpecular":[0.08,0.08,0.08],
        "mapDiffuseRepeat":[1,1],
        "transparent":false,
        "doubleSided":true,
        "mapBumpAnisotropy":1,
        "mapBump":"Wood.jpg",
        "colorDiffuse":[0.64,0.64,0.64]
    }],
    "vertices":[.....]
}
```

Comment: Have you added a light to your scene?

Comment: @WestLangley Yes, a directional light and an ambient light. Does this conflict with the mesh?

Comment: @user1760791 can you upload the entire.json file to test it

Comment: @Fast Snail This is the location of the json file: http://srater.com/game/js/blends/towerlevel1-5.json The image used is in the same folder : http://srater.com/game/js/blends/Wood.jpg

Comment: it is showing but completely black.

Comment: @user1760791 maybe texture is not yet loaded, try replacing with a 128x128 texture to check. Something like this happend to me once.

Comment: I replaced the texture... still doesn't work!